# DataTables, select rows and pass back ID for delete

Tags: jquery, sql, jsp, datatables

first time posting here but i really need help. Been working on this little project for a while and am finding Datatables to be next to useless but im being told i must use it....anyway Ive got it displaying our table from an ajax call to our SQL server. It needs to let the user select a few rows and click a delete button. It then SHOULD get the ID from each selected row and pass it back via an ajax call to our server which will then delete the value.

Ive tried about 5 diff row select methods, more delete attempts then i can count, and NOTHING is working. Ive asked for help on their support site several times over the past couple weeks and havent gotten a single reply so hoping the people here may be able to help more :)

Anyway heres my code: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dSLnT/3/#toggle-sidebar)  *UPDATED TO CURRENT*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var oTable = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
    //"bServerSide": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "sDom": 'pT<><f>rt<il>',
    "sAjaxSource": 'dataTable/getCmsGroupData',

    "aoColumns": [
                    { "mData": "id", "sTitle": "ID", 
                        "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                            return '<a href="cmsgroup_update?id='+ oObj.aData["id"] + '">' + oObj.aData["id"] + '</a>';
                          }},
                    { "mData": "version", "sTitle":"Version" },
                    { "mData": "name", "sTitle": "Name" },
                    { "mData": "description", "sTitle": "Description"},
                    { "mData": "notes", "sTitle": "Notes"},
                 ],
    "oTableTools": {
        "aButtons": [
                    "select_all",
                    "select_none", 
                    {
                        "sExtends": "text",
                        "sButtonText": "Create New Entry",
                        "fnClick": function ( nButton, oConfig, oFlash ) {
                            window.location = "cmsgroup_add";
                       }
                    }]
                }               
            });



$("#dataTable tbody").click(function(event) {
    $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
        $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
    });
    $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
});



function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal )
{
    var aReturn = new Array();
    var aTrs = oTableLocal.fnGetNodes();
    for ( var i=0 ; i<aTrs.length ; i++ )
    {

        if ( $(aTrs[i]).hasClass('row_selected') ) 
        {
            aReturn.push( aTrs[i] );
        }
    }
    return aReturn;
}

$("#delete").click(function(){

    selected = fnGetSelected(oTable);
    oTable.fnDeleteRow( selected[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dataTable/delete/cmsGroup",  
        data:   'tableData='+ $(selected).text(),  
        success: function(result) {  
            alert("worked!");
        }  
    });
});
} );
```

Any help would be great!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use fnDelete you have to pass the row or rows to delete to it from the datatable. In order to do that you have to use the oTableLocal.$("tr") to get the rows from the datatable.

```
function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal )
{
    var aReturn = new Array();
    oTableLocal.$("tr").filter(".row_selected").each(function (index, row){
        aReturn.push(row);// this should work, if not try aReturn.push($(row));
       //to get the information in the first column 
       aReturn.push($(row).eq(0).text());
    return aReturn;
}
```

Comment: i did that however it still has the same problem, rather then returning just the ID from the first cell in the row, it returns the entire row. Tried both ways you mentioned.

Comment: I updated my answer to pass the first columns information back.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the `aTrs[i]` in a `$()`, like so `$(aTrs[i]).hasClass('row_selected')` to get access to the jQuery methods.

You should also be using the `.on` handler rather than `click` or `live` because of the way that the datatable can recreate nodes and `live` is deprecated.

If you return an example of the response from `dataTable/getCmsGroupData`, I can be of more assistance.

Comment: Plugging those changes in now but in the mean time the get data:
{ "iTotalRecords": 24,"iTotalDisplayRecords": 24, "aaData": [{"id":1,"version":0,"name":"Network","description":"Corporate Network","notes":"Network Notes","displaysize":0},{"id":2,"version":5,"name":"Project","description":"","notes":"","displaysize":0},......and it goes on

Comment: its not working, i added $() to the call, and changed to .on like so:     
    $('.dataTable tbody tr').on('click', function () { but now its not working at all?

Comment: yea for me it loads locally (jfiddle gives me an error, does not look like its working to me?), pulls down data, but the delete command still wont work. Further the .on handler seems to have broken it. Now if i click on a row it does nothing, does not get 'selected'

Comment: jsfiddle has ben updated and is working for me.  I think your post is off.  What is the delete script expecting?  currently script is sending dom nodes (which actually just sends the string rendering in the post)

Comment: Updated to collect list of ids to delete, you should probably read over and use that instead.  A few other small changes (read comments in the fiddle)

Comment: just got to work this morning and am looking over the changes in jsfiddle. regarding the delete though it is expecting for example 'tableData=id' where id is from the selected row.

Comment: Implemented your code from jsfiddle and it does not work at all, the row select function is totally broken when using the .on handler.

Comment: Updated the fiddle again, ive got it working for single row selection using .click as .on never worked. when i select the row and hit delete it passes the WHOLE row back rather then just the first cell. IE: a row with ID:1 name:name value:value, it passes back '1namevalue', when i just need it to pass back '1'.

Comment: The code from JS Fiddle had a number of changes, each commented.  You replaced it with your original code again, so the changes are lost.  You can use `.find(':first-child a').text()` to get what your looking for.  If future, you should only replace specific code in the fiddle.  There was a change to use aaData initialization instead of ajax that made it testable on JSFiddle, along with other fixes, which is probably what broken things when you copy and paste the whole snippet it into your page.

Comment: oh dang....ive never posted on here or used jfiddle before, didnt see the comments. So sorry! What would i append '.find(':first-child a').text()' onto the end of?

Comment: It's performed on a jQuery wrapped object for the table row.  http://jsfiddle.net/HkSV9/9/ (apparently jsfiddle has version control :))

Answer (score 1):

Got it fixed! :) thanks for help everyone!!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
        //"bServerSide": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        "sDom": 'pT<><f>rt<il>',
        "aAjaxSource": 'dataTable/getCmsAttributeData',

        "aoColumns": [{
            "mData": "id",
            "sTitle": "ID",
            "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                return '<a href="cmsattribute_update?id=' + oObj.aData["id"] + '">' + oObj.aData["id"] + '</a>';
            }
        },
        {
            "mData": "version:",
            "sTitle": "Version"
                },
        {
            "mData": "name:",
            "sTitle": "name"
                },
        {
            "mData": "description",
            "sTitle": "Description"
                },
        {
            "mData": "cmsgroupid",
            "sTitle": "CMS Group ID"
                },
        {
            "mData": "masterattributeid",
            "sTitle": "Master Attribute ID"
                },
        {
            "mData": "notes",
            "sTitle": "Notes"
                }],
        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [{
                "sExtends": "text",
                "sButtonText": "Delete",
                "fnClick": function (nButton, oConfig, nRow) {
                    if (confirm('Are you sure want to delete this record?')) {
                        var list = $('tr.DTTT_selected > td.sorting_1 > a').map(function () {
                            return this.text;
                        }).get().join(",");
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "dataTable/delete/cmsGroup",
                            data: 'tableData=' + list,
                            success: function (result) {
                                alert("Entry Deleted");
                                $('tr.DTTT_selected').remove();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
     "select_all",
     "select_none",
            {
                "sExtends": "text",
                "sButtonText": "Create New Entry",
                "fnClick": function (nButton, oConfig, oFlash) {
                    window.location = "cmsgroup_add";
                }
     }]
        }
    });
});
```